# how to check if a message has replies in discord py

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I still don’t understand how I can track the next moment
I send a message, if there was no response to the message, then the bot writes that you missed the message and gives a link
There are these conditions when a message is considered read and there is a response to it:

```
def is_response_received(message):
    if message.reference:
        return True
    elif len(message.reactions) > 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

How can I prevent my bot from writing in the chat that there is a missed message, although there was a reply to it?
I need both messages: the first and the reply to it to be targeted and the bot to consider that the first message has a reply.
Please tell me how to implement this

My code works in such a way that the bot ignores the response, since it fits the conditions, but it ignores the message to which a response was made via “Reply”, although it should not

Answer (score 0):

Created a dictionary and compared by keys

```
def is_response_received(message):
    if message.reference and message.reference.message_id in message_map:
        return message_map[message.reference.message_id] == message.id
    elif not message.reference and (message.id in message_map and message_map[message.id] in message_map):
        return True
    elif len(message.reactions) > 0:
        return True
    return False


def save_message(message):
    message_map[message.id] = None
    if(message.reference):
        message_map[message.reference.message_id] = message.id
    logging.info(message_map)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).